# Construct AWS cost APi for getting total monthly costs or total daily usage for my account

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

i want to create/consume API for getting AWS cost daily and monthly details.
want to know how i can create api and check in the postman for getting cost details for my account.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable  [cost explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/) on your AWS account. Once you're done you can use [AWS SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html) to fetch cost results.

Comment: amazon dosn't provide direct api endpoints, instead they have provided sdk's/ aws cli to get useful information.

Comment: But i want to create a dashboard for showing aws cost usage by consuming their api's

Comment: As long as i know there's no direct way by amazon. As i mentioned you will have to  use boto3 with python or any other language to fetch required data like this https://github.com/linzhang-github/AWS-cost-explorer-API

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant iam permissions for cost explorer to your account/iam user. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-api.html

After that you are able to consume the api

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_Operations_AWS_Cost_Explorer_Service.html

with postman.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html

Comment: 503Service Unavailable, getting issue

Comment: This is API - http://ce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com with X-AMz_target == AWSInsightsIndexService.GetCostAndUsage  in the header

Comment: + set the Content-Type to `application/x-amz-json-1.1`